# how to use getjson to get a json object

Tags: javascript, json

```
var json = $.getJSON(url);
console.log(json.item);
```

It prints `undefined` in console, why?

What type of data will return when I use `$.getJSON`?

And how can I load the JSON file as a Object?

I have search many key words but I can't get a solution.

Comment: you’re missing the second arg which is a callback

Comment: [`$.getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) requires `callback` function. You can get response inside `callback`

Comment: Always read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

That function is actually making an ajax call and won't set `var json`, in your code.  So, you need a function to process the callback from the server.

```
$.getJSON( "test.js", function( json ) {
   console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.users[ 3 ].name );
});
```

I pulled that example from [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).